# Getting inverted index for indexed documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tf-idf

I have many documents (with an analyzed text field *title*). They have been indexed in Elasticsearch and now I need only to get the term frequency TF and inverse document frequency IDF for each term within the field *title* without having any query. (just indexing the documents and retrieving the inverted index of all terms in the field *title*)

Is that possible in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a [tutorial](https://github.com/apanimesh061/Term_Doc_Matrix_ES/blob/master/Term-Document%20Matrix%20from%20Elasticsearch.ipynb) on how to get a term-document matrix from ES. This does cover getting TFs but not IDFs. This was for ES 1.6.0 using Python.

For more you should have a look at the [TermVector API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/docs-termvectors.html).

Comment: Thanks @Animesh Pandey , what about the tokens? I applied an analyzer on the field *title* , can I get the resulting tokens for each document easily?

Comment: im looking for this too. have you got any info now?

Comment: Or you can just use: _termvectors to get the TF

Answer (score 2):

```
GET /YOUR_INDEX/YOUR_DOC_TYPE/YOUR_ID/_termvectors
{
  "fields" : ["YOUR_FIELD"],
  "term_statistics" : true,
  "field_statistics" : true
}
```

This will get the TF for every words in your document.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone still has a similar problem to OP's, I've created a [Python module called `inelastic`](https://github.com/federicotdn/inelastic) that prints out an approximation of an Elasticsearch inverted index for a given index and field.

Answer (score 0):

No. You could maybe find a way to hack it together somehow. And on a per query basis you can use the EXPLAIN api eg https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-explain.html But there is no API to return this info.