# Elasticsearch data comparison

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have two different Elasticsearch clusters,

One cluster is Elastcisearch 6.x with the data, Second new Elasticsearch cluster 7.7.1 with pre-created indexes.

I reindexed data from Elastcisearch 6.x to Elastcisearch 7.7.1

Is there any way to get the doc from source and compare it with the target doc, in order to check that data is there and it is not affected somehow.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a reindex the data will be indexed based on destination index mapping, so if your mapping is same you should get the same result in search, the `_source` value will be unique on both indices but it doesn't mean your search result will be the same. If you really want to be sure everything is OK you should check the `inverted index` generated by both indices and compare them for fulltext search, this data can be really big and there is not an easy way to retrieve it, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316152/getting-inverted-index-for-indexed-documents-in-elasticsearch) for getting `term-document matrix` .

Comment: I don't think so... As far as I understood it takes snapshots while reindexing from remote.
Moreover in my new cluster I pre-created index schema and removed deprecated type _doc field there... 

After reindexing I saw that docs reindexed and the type _doc is still there... 

Don't sure why you are saying that _source is unique on both clusters.

Comment: Reindex requires _source to be enabled for all documents in the source, so when you reindex it still will be the same in the destination. _doc is used by elastic as a default and single document type. it is used in index API to insert new document like POST indexname/_Doc/_id